# Is there an R package that expands the number of possible shapes for geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

So i'm making a ggtern plot where geom_point is being is used for a Ternary plot with 7 different groups. Each group has a different color, a different shape and a different fill. I want 7 shapes where the shapes can be filled with a different color. However the base R shape pallet only includes 5 such shapes (corresponding to the number 21-25). Is there an R package that expands this range (let say to include a regular pentagon and star).

```
p1 = ggtern(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,z=z, colour=group,fill = group, shape=group)) +
    geom_point(stroke=1.5,size=4) + theme_bw() +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23,24,25,5,6))
```

Comment: Perhaps worth having a look: https://github.com/xiangpin/ggstar

Comment: Thanks. It looks good but unfortunately for the specific purpose i want i'd like to be able to incorporate the new symbols into geom_point rather having to use a different layer (geom_star). I'm  actually using  ggtern rather than ggplot and geom_star and ggtern are not currently compatible.

Comment: Well, it might be helpful to include that in the question and adjust the example code accordingly. ggtern doesn't work too well with other ggplot2 extensions (or even ggplot2 itself).

Comment: Ok. I've updated the question accordingly. My thought was that ggtern is a less well known package, so people might be unfamiliar with is, whereas any solution for base ggplot2 that expands the shapes in geom_point would likely work (did not think that  some packages would work by adding a new layer).

Comment: In the ggplot2 extension system it is relatively easy to add a new geom/layer, but I have never seen a package expand base R's hardcoded palette of shapes in that way. I tried to extend one of ggtern's layers at some point, but it was a horrible mess to do because ggtern keeps a list of approved layers. Therefore, I don't expect there to be a extension-package based solution for your problem.